# Add (.CER) File association for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode4

I had a problem to add a file association that was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750846/add-file-associations-for-ios-in-xcode4), and now, it seems that the iOS reserve the 'cer' type, what i really need is to copy the .key and .cer  (along with a password) in my app, i suceded into getting the .key to be opened by the app, but no matter what i do, the .cer always open with *Settings.app*.

What i want to do is offer *iTunes File Sharing* and *Mail* for adding those resources.

Has anyone experienced this? is there a way to open the cer in a custom app?

Comment: I have this problem as well, have you been able to solve it?

Comment: Did not, i had to use **only** iTunes File Sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that is not possible (At least for ios4), had to use iTunes File Sharing, something else you can do is compress as a zip and load in your app (it might come in handy if you also need to copy other files along with it as a whole)